# Every standard Label now ambiguous because of another library

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, controls, custom-controls

I've used standard WPF Labels throughout my project. Now that I'm including the Telerik (3rd party library with it's own Label) every single standard Label is giving me an ambiguous error. Is there some other way of dealing with this other than going right through the class and specifying `Windows.Controls.Label`?

NOTE: I'm not using the Telerik Label at all, I'm using another control from it's library - so if there's a way to tell the class to treat every 'Label' as a Windows one then that'll do fine.

Comment: Obviously, one way would be to fully qualify the newly added control (the Telerik one) instead of adding its namespace, if it's used less than WinForms namespace controls.

Comment: @Groo: Should have been an answer. That is really *the* [best] way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to fully qualify the newly added control (the Telerik one) instead of adding its namespace, if it's used less than WinForms namespace controls.